# VBA Excel - Underline specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to ask if it is possible for a specific text to have an underline? As you can see in the codes below, I want the `fname`, `stud` and `grd` to be underlined when it shows in the `Sheet2` sheet. The codes are located at `Worksheet_Activate` of `Sheet2`.

```
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        
    For r = 9 To Lastrow
        If ws.Cells(r, 3) = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("K11").value) And ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 1 Then
                            
            fname = ws.Cells(r, 4).value
            stud = ws.Cells(r, 3).value
            grd = ws.Cells(r, 5).value + 1
            
            Text1 = "My name is "
            Text2 = " , my student ID is "
            Text3 = " and I'm grade "
        End If
            
    Next r
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("C72").value = Text1 & fname & Text2 & LRN & Text3 & grd & Text4
    End With
```

I tried using the `.Characters(17, 13).Font.Underline = True`, but I don't think I can use the `17,13` or any number since the value of `fname`, `stud`, and `grd` has a different length size.

Comment: You're nearly there :-)... now use the Lengths of the texts instead of the numbers to underline the varying range of characters. I don't think this can be done in one shot, but underlining like this "adds up" if you do it several times. I.e something like

`Dim CurrentCharacter as integer
.Characters(len(Text1),len(fname).Font.Underline = True 
CurrentCharacter = len(Text1)+len(fname)
.Characters(CurrentCharacter+len(Text2),len(stud).Font.Underline = True
CurrentCharacter = CurrentCharacter + len(Text2)+len(stud)
.Characters(CurrentCharacter+len(Text3),len(grd).Font.Underline = True`

Comment: I read your question too quickly and my comment allows for the three "Texts" to be variable, as well as the three "words". Simplify the above to ignore that if you want to, or include it to make your code robust to changes to the Texts too.

Comment: @Stax it is not aligned tho. Does it count the space?

Comment: @Stax your solution seems to work but I just replace the `len(Text1)` , `len(Text2)`, `len(Text3)` to its proper count.

Comment: @Stax the thing that I replace seems to be not accurate also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Stax pointed you in the right direction, and it looks like you're just about there with a solution.  I would further add storing the length of the `fname`, `stud` and `grd` strings in short variable names to minimise your code.

The relevant snippet would be (I'll let you work out how to do your loop etc.)

```
a = Len(fname)
b = Len(stud)
c = Len(grd)

With Sheet2.Range("C72")
    .Value = Text1 & fname & Text2 & stud & Text3 & grd
    .Characters(Start:=12, Length:=a).Font.Underline = True
    .Characters(Start:=36 + a, Length:=b).Font.Underline = True
    .Characters(Start:=51 + a + b, Length:=c).Font.Underline = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a way to underline required parts of your text.
It first concatenates your text, then applies underlying on needed words only.
You'll have to correct your algo (what is to be done line per line, "C72" etc)...

```
Sub WordToUnderlined(ByRef pRange As Range, ByVal pWord As String, _
    ByRef pPos As Integer)
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = InStr(pPos, pRange.Value, pWord, vbTextCompare)
    If pos > 0 Then
        With pRange.Characters(pos, Len(pWord))
            .Font.Underline = True
        End With
        WordToUnderlined pRange, pWord, pos + 1
    End If
End Sub

Sub TestMe()
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        
    For R = 9 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(R, 3) = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("K11").Value) And ws.Cells(R, 12).Value = 1 Then
                            
            fname = ws.Cells(R, 4).Value
            stud = ws.Cells(R, 3).Value
            grd = ws.Cells(R, 5).Value + 1
            
            Text1 = "My name is "
            Text2 = " , my student ID is "
            Text3 = " and I'm grade "
        End If
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
            .Range("C72").Value = Text1 & fname & Text2 & stud & Text3 & grd & Text4
            WordToUnderlined .Range("C72"), fname, 1
            WordToUnderlined .Range("C72"), stud, 1
            WordToUnderlined .Range("C72"), grd, 1
        End With
    Next R
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says `Out of stack space`.

Comment: When I clicked the `Debug` button, the highlighted line is `WordToUnderlined pRange, pWord, pos + 1`